# Regarding properties of matrices involved in Dirac equation

Tags: commutator, dirac-equation, dirac-matrices

In this [document](http://www.physics.ucdavis.edu/~cheng/teaching/230A-s07/rqm_all.pdf), after equation 62 on page 9, the author says that

> we can rewrite $\alpha^i \alpha^j \partial_i \partial_j$ as $\frac{1}{2} (\alpha^i \alpha^j + \alpha^j \alpha^i)\partial_i\partial_j$

Don't we need the $\alpha$ matrices to commute for this to be true? Why is this true?

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Answer (score 2):

The operator $\partial_i \partial_j$ is symmetric by switching $i$ and $j$. All tensors can be decomposed the following way :

$T_{ab} = T_{[ab]} + T_{\{ab\}}$

With $T_{\{ab\}}$ the symmetrized tensor ($\frac{1}{2}(T_{ab} + T_{ba})$)and $T_{[ab]}$ the antisymmetrized tensor ($\frac{1}{2}(T_{ab} - T_{ba})$).

Any antisymmetric tensor contracted with a symmetric tensor (or operator, in this case) will vanish. That is why you can ignore the commutator here.

Comment: Excellent, but since the partials only commute when they act on something smooth enough, the answer as to why it holds is that it only holds when the differential operator acts on something smooth enough.